# How can I listen to SwitchItem events on Android's Menu?

Tags: android, kotlin, onclick, menuitem

I am Using **SwitchCompat** on my **Toolbar**, I have a few Menu Items, one of which is this **Switch**.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<item
    android:id="@+id/map_toggle"
    android:title="Switch"
    app:actionLayout="@layout/switch_item"
    app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

I can Handle the click events of the regular MenuItems but I can't seem to trigger the SwitchCompat's event listener.

Any suggestions?

**Here is What I've tried so far. No luck**

```
    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.map_toggle -> {
                (item.actionView as SwitchCompat).setOnCheckedChangeListener(object: CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener{
                    override fun onCheckedChanged(button: CompoundButton?, checked: Boolean) {
                        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "$checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show()
                    }
                })
            }
            else -> Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
```